# NFC payment app

Tags: android, nfc

All I need is an app that clones my debit card and transmits it in front of the machine.

- Google Pay has a shitty policy against root.
- Samsung Pay only works on Samsung.
- Paypal is over 50MB.
- Venmo (frequently recommended app) doesn't even show on the store (found out it doesn't work in my country). Requires login and it's over 200MB installed.
- Other frequently recommended apps are for some virtual transferring.
- Neither my bank or card issuer (ironically) have this NFC ability. All they have is a *syncronize to GPay* function.

Anyone ?

My country is Brazil, but the ideal answer should be valid worldwide.

Phone is **Moto G6, Oreo 8.0**. But the same principle above applies.

Comment: If Venmo is not displayed in Play Store this does not mean it won't work. Have you tested if the [latest version from ApkMirror.com](https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s=com.venmo) works? Not that for security reasons apps like Google and Samsung Pay do not transmit the credit card number, instead the transmit pre-generated one-time token (some thing like generated on-time credit card numbers).

Comment: Thank you for the link and for the explanation. Unfortunately, Venmo has disturbing 146 MB !!!

Comment: Update: 146 BEFORE installed. After, more than 200MB. Plus, it DOESN'T work in my country

Comment: Please edit your question and add the country/countries where the app should work in. Also your used Android version should be added, too. More and more bank apps also have the functionality for NFC payments (but most banks also exclude rooted devices).